# Groovy - parse/ convert x-www-form-urlencoded to something like JSON

Tags: json, rest, parsing, groovy, x-www-form-urlencoded

this is my second try to explain a bit more precisely what I'm looking for ;-)

I set a webhook in Mailchimp that fires every time a new subscriber of an audience appears. Mailchimp sends a HTTP POST request to a Jira Sriptrunner REST endpoint.

The content type of this request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Within the Jira endpoint I would like to read the request data. How can I do that?

The payload (raw body) I receive looks like this:

```
type=unsubscribe&fired_at=2020-05-26+07%3A04%3A42&data%5Baction%5D=unsub&data%5Breason%5D=manual&data%5Bid%5D=34f28a4516&data%5Bemail%5D=examlple%40bla.com&data%5Bemail_type%5D=html&data%5Bip_opt%5D=xx.xxx.xxx.198&data%5Bweb_id%5D=118321378&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BEMAIL%5D=example%40bla.com&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BFNAME%5D=Horst&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BLNAME%5D=Schlemmer&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BCOMPANY%5D=First&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BADDRESS%5D%5Baddr1%5D=XXX
```

Now I would like to parse the data of the raw body into a JSON or something similiar.

The result might look like this:

```
{
 "web_id": 123,
 "email": "example@bla.com",
 "company": "First",
 ...
 }
```

Meanwhile I searched around a little and found something like the node.js "querystring" module. It would be great if there is something similiar within Groovy or any other way to parse the data of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `json` format.

Best regards and thanks in advance

Bernhard

Comment: do you want to parse the row body or response from requestbin.net ?

Comment: sorry for replying that late. basically, I would like to parse the raw body within a groovy script (within a scriptrunner REST endpoint). The requestbin.net response was only for checking, what payload is in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def body = "type=unsubscribe&fired_at=2020-05-26+07%3A04%3A42&data%5Baction%5D=unsub&data%5Breason%5D=manual&data%5Bid%5D=34f28a4516&data%5Bemail%5D=examlple%40bla.com&data%5Bemail_type%5D=html&data%5Bip_opt%5D=xx.xxx.xxx.198&data%5Bweb_id%5D=118321378&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BEMAIL%5D=example%40bla.com&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BFNAME%5D=Horst&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BLNAME%5D=Schlemmer&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BCOMPANY%5D=First&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BADDRESS%5D%5Baddr1%5D=XXX"

def map = body.split('&').collectEntries{e->
    e.split('=').collect{ URLDecoder.decode(it, "UTF-8") }
}

assert map.'data[merges][EMAIL]'=='example@bla.com'
map.each{println it}
```

prints:

```
type=unsubscribe
fired_at=2020-05-26 07:04:42
data[action]=unsub
data[reason]=manual
data[id]=34f28a4516
data[email]=examlple@bla.com
data[email_type]=html
data[ip_opt]=xx.xxx.xxx.198
data[web_id]=118321378
data[merges][EMAIL]=example@bla.com
data[merges][FNAME]=Horst
data[merges][LNAME]=Schlemmer
data[merges][COMPANY]=First
data[merges][ADDRESS][addr1]=XXX
```

Comment: Very cool! Thank you. Sorry for asaking again. Now the question is, how do I get the response dynamically into the '_body_' variable. I mean into the endpoint script?

Comment: better to ask another question because `endpoint script` could mean something different for you and for me )

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway! I guess I'll find my way now :-D

Answer (score 0):

A imple no-brainer groovy:

```
def a = '''
data[email_type]: html
data[web_id]: 123
fired_at: 2020-05-26 07:28:25
data[email]: example@bla.com
data[merges][COMPANY]: First
data[merges][FNAME]: Horst
data[ip_opt]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
data[merges][PHONE]: xxxxx
data[merges][ADDRESS][zip]: 33615
type: subscribe
data[list_id]: xxXXyyXX
data[merges][ADDRESS][addr1]: xxx.xxx'''

def res = [:]

a.eachLine{
  def parts = it.split( /\s*:\s*/, 2 )
  if( 2 != parts.size() ) return
  def ( k, v ) = parts
  def complexKey = ( k =~ /\[(\w+)\]/ ).findAll()
  if( complexKey ) complexKey = complexKey.last().last()
  res[ ( complexKey ?: k ).toLowerCase() ] = v
}

res
```

gives:

```
[email_type:html, web_id:123, fired_at:2020-05-26 07:28:25, 
email:example@bla.com, company:First, fname:Horst, ip_opt:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 
phone:xxxxx, zip:33615, type:subscribe, list_id:xxXXyyXX, addr1:xxx.xxx]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I edited the question slightly because I recognized that it was a little indistinct. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally. I hope you understand and maybe it helps others too ;-)

Starting from daggett's answer I did the following:

```
// Split body and remove unnecessary characters
def map = body.split('&').collectEntries{e->
    e.split('=').collect{ URLDecoder.decode(it, "UTF-8") }
}
// Processing the map to readable stuff
def prettyMap = new JsonBuilder(map).toPrettyString()
// Convert the pretty map into a json object
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonObject = slurper.parseText(prettyMap)
```

(The map looks pretty much like in daggett's answer.
[prettyMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Lis.png))

Then I extract the keys:

```
// Finally extracting customer data
def type = jsonObject['type']
```

And I get the data I need. For example

```
Type : subscribe
...
First Name : Heinz
...
```

Thanks to daggett!